# Why the size of pointer to array is always 8 in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Belows are simple code that compares size of array itself and size of pointer to array.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(){   
        int kkarray[100]= {1,0,};
        int (*kkpointer) = kkarray;

        printf("size of array using array itself : %ld \n" , sizeof(kkarray));        
        printf("size of array using pointer to array : %ld \n" , sizeof(kkpointer));   
}
```

but the result is,

```
400
8
```

I could understand that the first value is 400, but second one,, i think that it also should be 400 because as i assigned a pointer that points to array, kkpointer, it kinda acts like name of array, which is const address value. For example, i can get the first value of array using kkpointer[0].
I want to know why i got '8' instead of 400.
I don't think the '8' is the size of address itself.
please let me know. Thanks

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function - it is evaluated at compile time. It is giving you the size of *the pointer itself* - it cares nothing about what it points to.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart fortunately it doesn't care about the pointee, or else it would be useless.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: You are right with the first part, it's not a function (it couldn't be and do what it does anyway). But it is evaluated at compile-time. Unless it isn't, which only happens for VLAs (type or variable).

Comment: @Deduplicator gahh I know that. Thought one thing, and typed the other! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of any pointer is always `8` **on your platform**, so it's platform dependent.

The `sizeof` operator doesn't care where the pointer is pointing to, it gives the size of the pointer, in the first case it just gives the size of the array, and that is not the same.

This is a quote from **§ 6.5.3.4**, **¶ 2** N1570 draft

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand**. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant

and **§ 6.5.3.4**, **¶ 4**

> When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or
>   signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. **When applied to an
>   operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array**.103) When
>   applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of
>   bytes in such an object, including internal and trailing padding

so as you can see, when applied to the array, it gives the total bytes. But if you pass a pointer, then the result will be the size of it's type.

Comment: `it is 4 in 32bit systems.` ???!!

Comment: @al-Acme Why does that surprise you?

Comment: It doesn't have to be 4 in 32 bit systems. Basically, the size of a pointer is whatever the implementation says it is.

Comment: @juanchopanza I just remebered the `x32` linux.

Comment: IIRC, x32 uses 32-bit pointers in long mode on the x86-64.

Comment: Pointers to different types do not have to have the same size or representation.  On most modern desktop and server systems they usually do, but there are some old or oddball architectures where, say, a `char *` is larger than an `int *`, or an object pointer is wider than a function pointer, etc.

Comment: Excuse me, but what is ' § 6.5.3.4, ¶ 2 N1570 draft' ?? I think this reference is really great.

Comment: @Chois: it's a reference to the latest online draft of the C language standard, found at [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)